# for loop on Text + number on Apps Script

Tags: javascript, for-loop

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CRFd.png I'm trying to use loop to set value "Hello1" in cell F11, "Hello2" in cell F12, "Hello3" in cell F13, then continue until "Hello10". The Cell F10 already has the word "Hello" on it. So far I only managed to show the value "1" on everything

[image].

Here's how I wrote the script:

```
  function Exercise2() {

  var exercise2 = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = exercise2.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var helloCell = activeSheet.getRange(10, 6).getValue();

  activeSheet.getRange(1, 1).moveTo(activeSheet.getRange("F10"));

  for(var x=10;x<21;x++){
  var helloCell = activeSheet.getRange(x, 6).getValue();
  helloCell = helloCell+1;
  activeSheet.getRange(x, 6).setValue(helloCell);
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop can be greatly simplified to somthing like this:

```
for(var x = 1; x < 11; x++) {
    activeSheet.getRange(x + 9, 6).setValue("Hello" + x);
}
```

This will:

1. Create a loop that runs from `1` to `11` stored in `x`.
2. Set the value of the cell at `x + 9` to the value `"Hello" & x`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into it however, by following this I only got zero on everything. Basically, what I'm trying to get at is this 


https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CRFd.png.

Comment: I think I made a mistake in using the VBA-style syntax for string concatenation which is why you are getting `0` instead of text.  I'll edit the question, but `"Hello " & x` _should be_ `"Hello" + x` (note the `+` instead of `&`).